# Simplest way to detect a Distribution build at compile time

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

Would like to be able to do the following

```
#ifdef Distribution
    /// code...
#endif
```

Could make a *Distribution* build configuration and add the `Distribution` preprocessor macro. 
Problem with this is that the *Distribution* conf should always have the same configuration as the *Release* conf except for the extra preprocessor macro. So if the *Release* conf setting changes it becomes a maintenance problem.

- Is there a way to make a build configuration inherit from another configuration similar to how a targets build settings inherit from the project build settings?
- Or can you dynamically add a preprocessor macro as a run script in the Archive scheme's *pre-actions* section?
- Maybe could do it with configuration files? But still want Xcode to be able to warn and modify to the recommended settings as new xcode versions are installed.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I needed something similar. In Xcode, go to the Build Settings for your project or target. In there you can set up Preprocessor Macros for your build configurations. They will be available in your code.

[image: Preprocessing options]

In my screenshot above, suppose you want to use the Debug Distribution configuration. In code, you can use `#if DEBUG` or `#if RELEASE_DEBUG` as appropriate, because both are defined with that configuration.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, duplicates of build configurations are a hassle because if changes are made to the settings of the original, the duplicated configuration must change too. This would be accepted answer if the configuration could inherit from another configuration, such as Release. Thanks.